# Smooth contour lines/correctly extract contour lines from a DEM in QGIS

Tags: qgis-3, dem, line, contour, smoothing

I have a DEM obtained as a result of the interpolation of elevation points `TIN Interpolatin`:

[image]

I extracted the contour lines in QGIS and the result is this:

[image]

After I tried to apply the `Line Smoothing` tool:

[image]

[image]

As shown in the picture there are still several "angular" corners. 
I suppose there is a more correct way to extract contour lines and process them. I have seen that similar questions have been asked in the past on this forum but mostly the solutions were about QGIS 2 compatible plug-ins.

What I need is to find in QGIS a quick way to process contour lines as correctly as possible and get a smoothed effect from the contours.

Comment: you don't have enough points to get a smooth output

Comment: so you think that's the best result I can obtain?

Comment: Please include a screenshot of the Line Smoothing tool window with the parameters used.

Comment: Ian and Gabriel have both made good comments.  I would add that the QGIS Plugin repository has two additional plugins that you may find helpful: *Cartographic Line Generalization* and *Generalizer3*.  I have not used either one, but you might try experimenting with them if the *Line Smoothing* tool cannot meet your needs.

Comment: If height accuracy at your sample points isn't paramount and smooth contours are essential, consider passing the DEM through a filter. Your TIN is too jagged in the first place.

Comment: I read that some people recommend using the Gaussian filter. Are there any others?

Comment: @ddomizia, have you tried it with your data?  If so, what was the result?

Comment: @StuSmith what do you mean by "my data"?

Comment: @ddomizia I mean your "...DEM obtained as a result of the interpolation of elevation points..."

Comment: @ddomizia The Line Smoothing tool, which you have displayed, has a Gaussian option.  You can access it by dropping down the "Method" section.

Comment: @StuSmith I tried. The result by setting the as method "Gaussian" and the value 10 in "sigma" is the smoothing of the sharp corners that you see in the final image of my question. However, on the other hand, the appearance of the rest of the cuntour remains rather unchanged from the source file. In any case, I still do not obtain the hoped-for result.